# database query to get notification read by friends of users

Tags: mysql

I have two tables for notification and one table for friend_list. One notification tbale is that has the notification info who created and type and all and second which marks which friend has read the notification. the was able to retrieve the notification created by the user to be displayed only to user's friend. But now I want from the second table named notification read to display notification which are unread to the user's friend.

The query I made is (from notification + friend_list table)

```
$sql3=mysql_query("select n.*,f.friend_id,f.uid,f.status from notification n,friend_list f  where f.uid='$id' and f.status='1' and n.title_text='Global Notification'   and n.user_id in ('$id' , f.friend_id)  and n.owner_user_id=f.friend_id    order by n.time_stamp desc");
```

now how to get notification unread by friend?

The second table is

```
uid (friend_id)
notification_id
is_read
```

now I want a query with my existing query to get notifications unread by friends.

Answer (score 0):

Let's supose that:

- `'$id'`  is the id of user that raise notification
- `n.user_id` is user that raises notification
- `n.owner_user_id` is user that receive notification

The query is:

```
select 
   n.*,f.friend_id,f.uid,f.status 
from 
   notification n 
inner join
   friend_list f  
       on n.owner_user_id=f.friend_id  
inner join
   notification_read nr 
       on nr.notification_id = n.notification_id and
          nr.uid = f.friend_id
where 
   f.status='1' and 
   n.title_text='Global Notification'   and 
   n.user_id  = '$id' and
   nr.is_read = 0
order by n.time_stamp desc
```

***Edited*** due new OP comment.

Comment: we are using 3 three tables here , notification + friend_list(the query i gave) and notification_read (the query i want of all 3 combination)

Comment: fixed. Please, notice that I don't have all data schema details. This is an approach. You shuld make last changes to fit to your needs. Ask for more help if something is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT n.*,f.friend_id,f.uid,f.status
FROM notification n
     INNER JOIN friend_list f
        ON n.owner_user_id = f.friend_id
     INNER JOIN second_table s
        ON f.friend_id = s.uid AND
           n.notification_id = s.notification_id
WHERE f.uid='$id' AND
      f.status='1' AND
      n.title_text='Global Notification' AND
      n.user_id IN ('$id' , f.friend_id) AND
      s.is_read = 0
ORDER BY n.time_stamp DESC;
```

Comment: we are using 3 three tables here , notification + friend_list(the query i gave) and notification_read (the query i want of all 3 combination)

Comment: nope not working its not getting any notification . cant i get a seperate query to get unread notifications as i have already made a query to get notifications according to friends , and  i just nw need those which are unread using the second table